# What's wrong with this pipe?

Tags: c, pipe, unix

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>  
#include <pthread.h>

int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int enteroParaElPipe;  
    int IDPROGRAMACLIENTE=getpid(); 
    printf("%d",IDPROGRAMACLIENTE);

    if((mkfifo("pipe",0666))==-1) 
    {
        perror("error creating pipe, type 1");
        exit(1);
    }

    if((enteroParaElPipe=open("pipe",O_WRONLY))==-1)
    {
       perror("error creating pipe, type 2");
       exit(1);
    }

    char comando[200];

    if(scanf("%199s", comando) == 1)
         puts(comando);

    int written;
    escritos=write(enteroParaElPipe,"HOLA\n",5);
    printf("Written: %d\n",written);
    close(enteroParaElPipe);

    return 0;
}
```

When trying to run this code I get:

```
error creating pipe: Invalid argument
```

Why?

(Modifications based on the first answers added)

Comment: Why are you passing a pid to `mkfifo`? You should also use different messages for the different error cases so you can tell which one happened..

Comment: your code formatting was horrible.  I improved it a little, and its still ugly.  You want people to go through your code? the least you can do is format it.

Comment: @abelenky: yeah, sorry. I took out the un-formated, irrelevant parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to [mkfifo](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkfifo) is a mode_t representing the permissions on the fifo.

Try: `mkfifo("pipe", 0666);`

Answer (score 2):

Why are you passing `getpid()` as the 2nd argument for mkfifo?

The 2nd argument is the mode, as in, the FIFO file's permissions. Type `man 3 mkfifo` for more information!

Cheers.

Comment: @omgzor: `0600` is likely to be what you want to pass as the second argument.

Comment: The same? Invalid argument? Uhm,... do you have permissions on that directory? Are we talking about a filesystem that supports FIFOs? (For example, a FAT32 system wouldn't).